# IE11 Sass Calc for animation timing not working

Tags: css, sass

I'm using Sass and trying to get some animations to work in IE11 (they work perfectly in Chrome). I have a set of timing variables cascade down and manage each either via calc function.

Example sass with variable defs

```
$load-modal: 0.2s;
$post-load-modal-delay: calc(#{$load-modal} + 0.1s);
$display-columns: 0.2s;

$display-summary: 0.2s;
$post-display-summary-delay: calc(#{$post-load-modal-delay} + #{$display-columns} + 0.1s);

@include animate(fadeIn $display-summary $post-display-summary-delay forwards);
```

IE11 translates this as the below, and is highlighted in red indicating invalid css

```
animation: fadeIn 0.2s calc(calc(0.2s + 0.1s) + 0.2s + 0.2s + 0.1s) forwards
```

Whereas Chrome reads that same line but for some reason doesn't complain and behaves as desired

If I delete the calcs for the animation timing is works just fine in IE11 as well. How can I get calc to work with Sass variables in IE11 for animation timings?

**update**

After a bit of poking around I'm thinking this is due to trying to use seconds in the calculation. Not sure why it'd work in Chrome and not IE11 yet though would love anyone's insight. After more poking all the interpolation seems on point and seconds are marked as seconds just fine, but still the calc is not actually doing a calculation.

**update2**

After more fiddling it seems IE solely has trouble calculating time units
It refuses to allow calcs with time.  `calc(0.1s + 0.1s)` causes error whereas just using `0.2s` works fine

Any suggestions on how I can use calc to help manage my animation timings and still get IE to behave?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need calc – simply use addition without interpolation

```
$load-modal: 0.2s;
$post-load-modal-delay: $load-modal + 0.1s;
$display-columns: 0.2s;
$display-summary: 0.2s;
$post-display-summary-delay: $post-load-modal-delay + $display-columns + 0.1s;


// $post-display-summary-delay is 0.6s
```

Comment: that did it thanks @Jakob E! Having some kind of other issue now where the animation isn't actually firing unless I uncheck and re-check it in the Inspector

Comment: How is it supposed to be triggered does it depend on user interaction – e.g. hover?

Comment: no, on a class being added. The class gets added and shows up in the Inspector, but doesn't actually trigger until I uncheck and then re-check the box -- works perfectly fine in Chrome as is by the way

Comment: can you make a fiddle/codepen (just use the CSS output)?

Comment: hmm just tried to reproduce and my (incredibly simplified example) is working in IE11, just not the real deal, so at least that gives me something to hunt down

Comment: sounds familiar – happy hunting ;-)

Comment: fyi fwiw, I was removing and then adding a class to trigger the animation. I had to wrap the add in a 10ms timeout and now it's firing.